# Как пользоваться справочником developer.android.com

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, я не так давно начал изучать Java android, и мне бы хотелось научиться пользоваться официальным справочником. Но я не могу понять, на сайте описано куча методов и к ним добавлено небольшое описание. Я сделал скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но где на их сайте найти пример реализации Html.ImageGetter класса, и какие методы он поддерживает?

К примеру на сайте php есть отличная документация, которая описывает саму функцию и указаны несколько примеров реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вам нужно вбить интересующий класс\метод в поиск по ресурсу (верхний правый угол сайта). Так вы получите всю информацию, связанную с данным классом\методом.

Дело в том, что в разделе API описания некоторых (не основных) компонентов очень скудные, но кроме этого еще есть разделы: курсы, руководства, примеры и др. в которых даются практические и более развернутые пояснения (правда тоже далеко не по всем классам). Линковка же между ресурсами сайта по не основным классам API тоже довольно убогая, это, безусловно, недостаток документации Android, приходится пользоваться поиском, но нередки случаи (как в вашем примере), когда все что можно узнать из документации - пара скупых строк в разделе API, в то время, как по основным классам прямо в разделе API огромные портянки с описанием и отличная линковка на доп. ресурсы, например [по классу `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Если в документации недостаточно сведений, приходится искать сторонние ресурсы, например, на английском SoF присутствуют разработчики Android (и просто грамотные парни) и обычно всегда готовы прояснить непонятные моменты (или уже давно сделали это).

То, какие интерфейсы, методы, константы и прочее определены для каждого класса, полностью указывается на странице API этого класса, в разделе Summary. В вашем случае, для класса [`Html.ImageGetter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter.html) определен только один метод `getDrawable()`, что видно и на вашем же скриншоте.

Comment: Я так понял android предоставил нам паззлы которые можно по своему группировать?

Answer (score 3):

[developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/package-summary.html)

в меню есть примеры и полное описание всех свойст, атрибутов в обектов. В справочнике переходите на нужный пункт и смотрите как с ним работать. В верхней части будет писать с какой версии апи доступен тот или иной метод

[image: скрин меню]

Comment: Я нашел нужный мне метод `Html.ImageGetter` Но я не знаю как его применить. Залез в гугл, я обнаружил вот такую схему реализации `Html.ImageGetter htmlImageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            int resId = resources.getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Drawable ret = resources.getDrawable(resId);
            ret.setBounds(0, 0, ret.getIntrinsicHeight(), ret.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return ret;
        }
    };` А на сайте об этом не слова

Comment: что вы хотите получить используя данный метод?

Comment: Он находит в файле изображения указаны как в HTML `<img src='test'/>`  и выводит его на экран

Comment: можно получить кусок кода и полностью HTML и конкретное описание того что вы хотите в результате иметь

Comment: @Sergiyss "А на сайте об этом не слова" пользоваться поиском по всем сайтам - это вполне естественно. и пхп вы использовали бы гораздо эффективнее, если бы пользовались поиском по всем сайтам. вот чудаки. или вы думаете, что авторы Android боги и все всегда делают правильно и идеально? линуксоиды и не претендуют на это. наоборот, у них "открытая" модель, "не нравится - сделай лучше, а мы не обязаны", вот сообщество и делает, а вы не юзаете